# setting value in form select in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, select

When I click on the button , I want that button to set the value of the select in react.
Suppose my list has = 10,15,20,25,30
As per the code , the value is set to be 10 default since its the 1st object in array .

What I want is, when I click the button I want the value to be set as 25 .

```
const [formData,setFormData] =useState({name:'',age:''})

//this is form submit
const handleSubmit = (event)=>{
setFormData({age:event.target.age.value})
}

//this will be my another button which will set my value to 25
//const randomButton = () => {}

<select
className='custom-select'
id='age'
name='age'
required
>
{ageOptions.map((row,index)=>{return <option value={row.value}>{row.label}</option>})}
</select>
```

Comment: I see neither your array, nor the button you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Something like that ? :

    

import React, { useState } from "react";

const options = [
  { label: "rep 1", value: "first" },
  { label: "rep 2", value: "second" },
  { label: "rep 3", value: "third" },
];


    export default function App() {
      const [val, setVal] = React.useState("zero")
    
      const goTwo = () => setVal('second')
    
      const handleChange = (inp) => setVal(inp.target.value)
    
      return (
        <div >
            <button onClick={goTwo}>Go Two</button>
            <select
              onChange={handleChange} >{options.map(e=><option value={e.value} selected={e.value===val?'selected':''}>{e.label}</option>)}
            </select>
            --> {val}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-margulis-h6dgi?file=/src/App.js